# Delete Rows from Dataframe, after Grand Total Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading PDF's and getting data into Dataframe.

| EmpID | Team_Name | Cost | No_Emps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | Sam | 25,689 | 2 |
| AA2 | Tom | 78,368 | 3 |
| AA3 | Dick | 125,369 | 5 |
| AA4 | Harry | 32,658 | 2 |
| AA5 | Joan | 22,685 | 2 |
| Grand Total: |  | 284,769 | 17 |
| xxx |  |  |  |
| yyy |  |  |  |
| dfg | nnn |  |  |
| fgh |  | xxx |  |
| vhg |  |  | ttt |
| ppp |  |  | ddd |

There will be n number of rows after Grand Total, I need to exclude All rows after the `EmpID = 'Grand Total'`.

Comment: If the answers solved your issue, kindly accept the one that was the most useful. If not do let know what the answers missed as a comment. More info on what to do when someone answers -> [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have pandas df :

```
df = df.iloc[: df.index[df['EmpID'] == 'Grand Total:'][0]+1])
```

output:

```
          EmpID Team_Name    Cost No_Emps
0           AA1       Sam   25689       2
1           AA2       Tom   78368       3
2           AA3      Dick  125369       5
3           AA4     Harry   32658       2
4           AA5      Joan   22685       2
5  Grand Total:       NaN  284769      17
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the index of the "Grand Total" row.

```
index = df.index
gt_index = index[df["EmpID"] == "Grand Total:"]

new_df = df.drop(index=index[gt_index[0]+1:])
new_df
```